# searching for html values from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, input, textbox

I have a table which is dynamically created based on the amount of results returned.
In each row there is a cell (created from c# code) with a textbox like

`"<input id='textbox" + i + "'type='text'/`>"

so textbox0, 1, 2, etc.

My question is, how to obtain each textbox's value in the c# code, after a user inputs something?

i.e you can't just go textbox1.Text to get the value since the code behind page has no idea what textbox1 is.

Comment: Does it have to be done server side or can you use jQuery?

Comment: While you create them, add `runat="server"`, it shall make it available in C# like `textbox1.Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should specify a unique name for your inputs :

```
"<input id='textbox" + i + "' name='textbox" + i + "' type='text'/>"
```

then at server side you can get each textbox's value by this name :

```
string textbox1Value = Request.Form["textbox1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript code.

```
<script language="javascript">
var txt = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++)
{
 // do what you want ...
}
</script>
```